# Redirecting a cURL GET-request for a website's subfolder to another IP

Tags: http, curl, redirect, get, hosts

I'm having a bit of a problem with some legacy code that utilizes a hardcoded domain including specific subfolders. The webserver always responds with `{"err":1200, "msg":"invalid"}`. Thing is, I have no control over editing the code. Since this code has like 100+ hardcoded different HTTP-GET requests, which are working just fine, and the only bit that doesn't work is when the GET-requests target a specific subfolder. Incidentially the program expects just a simple response:
`{"err":0}`
So I decided to quickly set up a local Apache and edited the /etc/hosts file to redirect all requests to 127.0.0.1. I created a html-file with solely the expected response in it and set it as the default 404-page. Of course this only worked for that single line of code that requests the aforementioned subfolder of the site. *Obviously that completely wrecked all the other lines of the code.*

**TL;DR**
I need to redirect just a single HTTP-GET request to another IP while all the other requests remain the same. The request in question is directed at a specific subfolder. I'd like to use something comparable to the /etc/hosts file - just with additional directory parameters instead of just a whole domain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are not talking about a redirect. A redirect is rather easy, as you can just configure any webserver to just send a `302` response to a new server. In apache, look at RedirectMatch or 'rewrites'.

If that works for you, easy. If not and you want to handle all endpoints (from the old and new system) from the same domain, your best option is probably a reverse proxy. This is also supported by Apache and many other webservers.

The way this basically works is:

- If a path matches a certain pattern, proxy the request to your new system.
- If not, proxy the request to your old system

I would suggest you read the documentation for reverse proxies on your webserver of choice and try to devise a good configuration.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input. This looks like it'd be just what I was looking for. I'll test it later and comment the results.

Comment: a2enmodded  the following:
proxy
proxy_http
proxy_ajp
rewrite
deflate
headers
proxy_connect
proxy_html

and added :
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
ProxyPass "/targetfolder/"  "http://127.0.0.1/"
ProxyPassReverse "/tagertfolder/"  "http://39.106.23.42/targetfolder"

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

parameterized curl commands seem to always end up with a http500. error returned from my local apache. 

Did I miss anything or why won'r the request be drected at the called external IP?

Comment: Super hard to read this, might be better as a new question.